# CKEditor inserting <q> in all <p>

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I'm applying a CKEditor in one `<textarea>` with the follow content:

```
<q>
<p>this is paragraph one.</p>
<p>this is paragraph two.</p>
</q>
```

So, i want quote all those paragraphs. But, when i apply the CKEditor, the HTML above transform in this HTML:

```
<q>
<p><q>this is paragraph one.</q></p>
<p><q>this is paragraph two.</q></p>
</q>
```

This is my function to create the CKEditor instance:

```
function create_ckeditor_instance(comment) {
    comment = '<q>' + comment.trim() + '</q>';

    var html = '<textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="reply-textarea">';
    html += comment;
    html += "</textarea>";

    $('reply-comment-wrapper').html(html);

    CKEDITOR.replace('reply-textarea');

    CKEDITOR.instances['reply-textarea'].on('instanceReady', function (event) {
      var range = CKEDITOR.instances['reply-textarea'].createRange();
      range.moveToPosition( range.root, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_END );
      CKEDITOR.instances['reply-textarea'].getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
      CKEDITOR.instances['reply-textarea'].focus();
    });

}
```

My question is, how to avoid this behavior of the CKEditor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content model of [`<q>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-q-element)  is [Phrasing Content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2), but  the [`<p>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-p-element) element is [Flow Content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2) and as of that not a valid child of `<q>`.

You would need to use [`<blockquote>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-blockquote-element) instead.

The outer `<q></q>` looks like a bug to me and but I can't reproduce it here, with the current version with CKEditor.

But that it is transformed to:

```
<p><q>this is paragraph one.</q></p>
<p><q>this is paragraph two.</q></p>
```

is correct, because wrapping `<q>` around those two `<p>` would produce invalid code.

Comment: Nice, when i use <blockquote> everything better than expected!! :D

Comment: @VitorLuis as a little note: CKEditor cannot deal (at least the last time I checked)  with [_transparent elements_](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#transparent)  like `<a>`, while it is valid in HTML5 to have `<a><p>test</p><p>test</p></a>` CKEditor does the same to like in your example transforming it to `<p><a>test</a></p><p><a>test</a></p>`